# Status expected:<200> but was:<400> error with MockMvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I have an issue with testing my Spring Boot Controller I'm trying to solve for the past few hours. I'm quite new to coding, but I got that assignment in my company nevertheless.

**My Controller:**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/data", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getData(@RequestParam("core") List<String> core, @RequestParam("date") List<String> date,
        @RequestParam("state") String state, @RequestParam("area") List<String> area,
        @RequestParam("type") List<String> type, @RequestParam("analyt") String analyt,
        @RequestParam("wp") String wp, @RequestParam("subDesc") String subDesc,
        @RequestParam("anaMonitor") List<String> anaMonitor, @RequestParam("ecoMonitor") List<String> ecoMonitor,
        @RequestParam("subType") List<String> subType, @RequestParam("needed") List<String> needed,
        @RequestParam("notify") List<String> notify, @RequestParam("available") List<String> available,
        @RequestParam("phase") List<String> phase, @RequestParam("subAvailable") List<String> subAvailable,
        @RequestParam("subShipped") List<String> subShipped, @RequestParam("external") List<String> external,
        @RequestParam("valid") List<String> valid, @RequestParam("contract") List<String> contract) {
    FilterInputModel model = new FilterInputModel(core, date, state, type, area, analyt, wp, subDesc, anaMonitor, ecoMonitor, subType, needed, notify, available, phase, subAvailable, subShipped, external, valid, contract);  
        return new ResponseEntity<>(vaultService.getFilteredFields(model), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**Here's a test:**

```
@DisplayName("Controller Test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    private FilterInputModel model;
    
    @MockBean
    private TestService testService;
    
    @Autowired
    ControllerTest() {
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        
    @Test
    void getDataTest() throws Exception {
        List<Object> response = new ArrayList<>();
        when(vaultService.getFilteredFields(model))
            .thenReturn(response)
            .thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);
            
        this.mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/data")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                    .accept("application/json"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
                .andExpect(result -> assertEquals(response, result.getAsyncResult()));
   }
```

And here's an answer I got. It says in an error message that 'Required request parameter 'core' for method parameter type List is not present' but that answer didn't help me much. I'm still stuck looking for an answer.

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/data
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = hr.ogcs.ltt.api.lttapi.controller.LttController
           Method = hr.ogcs.ltt.api.lttapi.controller.LttController#getData(List, List, String, List, List, String, String, String, List, List, List, List, List, List, List, List, List, List, List, List)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 400
    Error message = Required request parameter 'core' for method parameter type List is not present
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
Expected :200
Actual   :400
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:212)
   at hr.ogcs.ltt.api.apicontroller.ControllerTest.getDataTest(ControllerTest.java:126) <31 internal lines>
   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)<9 internal lines>
   at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)<48 internal lines>
```

Comment: "but that answer didn't help me much" how exactly didn't that help you? it basically explains exactly what's wrong with your call.

Comment: RequestParameters are requiered at default. So you need to send them in your Test or change the RequestParam to be optional:
@RequestParam(value = "core",required = false). Have a look at the Javadoc of the RequestParam class it explains the settings and the default values for each one.

Comment: You are testing a completlely different method then you posted here. You show a method for `/data` you are testing `/api/ecotox`. The last uses JSON the first uses parameters.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've edited my post, sorry for that.

Comment: You are sending an empty request, without parameters (and as json). Hence it fails as parameters are required.

Comment: @mszalbach & M.Deinum >> thank you guys, that solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending the required parameters (the parameters annotated with `@RequestParam`) to the method. By default they are all required. If not present Spring blocks the request with missing arguments.

Example of sending parameters:

```
mvc.perform(
    MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/public/xpto/{code}", "21212").param("core", "ubababacaio")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).characterEncoding("UTF-8")).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: Okay, I've added something like
`this.mockMvc.perform(
                MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/ecotox").param("cores", "core",
                                "dates", "date","states", "state"
                                )
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .accept("application/json"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(result -> assertEquals(response, result.getAsyncResult()));
    }`
But I'm still having the same error.

Comment: Thank you a ton! :) I've solved the problem by applying your code. Sorry for not getting you right away, I'm fairly new to Spring Boot and testing, so It took me a while to set the parameters right.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all those parameters in a MultiValueMap and pass them all at once!

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> allParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(){{
    put(<KEY>, <VAL>)
    ...
}}

MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/ecotox").params(allParams).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).accept("application/json"))
.andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
```

.andExpect(result -> assertEquals(response, result.getAsyncResult()));     }